# How to bring salesforce report in .Net website?

Tags: reporting, dashboard, .net, partner, partner-wsdl

I want to display salesforce report/dashboard in my website.
or any way to get report data with partner api? 
Can any one help me?

Thanks,
Bhavesh

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is the analytics API. Please have a look at it. [Analytic API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics).

Comment: Thanks manjitsingh.i am new in salesforce. i can see that Analystic report used with visual force page but i want report in my own website.can you please help?.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Analytics REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/) to both get a list of available reports, and to run the reports and extract the required data.

In the simplest case you can get a [list of reports](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_recentreportslist.htm). Then once you have the Report ID, do [a synchronous run](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_get_reportdata.htm#example_sync_reportexecute) to get the data of that report.